# getting repeated data from firebasev9 with react.js on first reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

let temp = []

const {
  id
} = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    const condition = where("uid", "==", id)
    const q = query(collection(db, "blogs-post"), condition)
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      temp.push(doc.data())
      setData([...temp])
    });
  }
  getData();
}, [])

return ( 
  <div className="Wrapper">
    <Dashboarditem Items={data}/> 
  </div>
);
```

I am getting repeated data on first reload as you can see in the above image i am getting the same data two times even though it does not exist in the database how can I stop that

Comment: Can you share the image that you are referring to?

Comment: @Dharmaraj https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XyyNxZvAInX6yzbvzr4cfIaY-HacahSA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't see any code that uses UUID for keys. Can you share the relevant component? The issue might be there instead of in useEffect

Comment: @Dharmaraj as you can see i am not supposed to get the 3 and 4 object which is repeated data of above object what is the reason of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason is that React Strict Mode is on

> StrictMode renders components twice (on dev but not production) in order to detect any problems with your code and warn you about them (which can be quite useful). - @rangfu

The problem is being caused due to the *temp* variable being declared outside the useEffect, when useEffect is called for a second time this causes the same values to be pushed into it while the previous values are already present, I suggest that you **add the temp array inside the useEffect** as such :

```
useEffect(() => {
  let temp = [];
  const getData = async () => {
    const condition = where("uid", "==", id)
    const q = query(collection(db, "blogs-post"), condition)
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      temp.push(doc.data())
      setData([...temp])
    });
  }
  getData();
}, [])
```

This should fix your problem